# How do I access flask-websocket sessions from inside flask functions

Tags: python, flask, websocket, flask-socketio, flask-session

As the title states I'm having issues with accessing flask-websocket sessions from the flask functions. I have realised they are different and probably stored differently and tried to solve this using the flask-session library to no avail.

I have made some boilerplate code illustrating my problem.

```
from flask import Flask, session,render_template,url_for,redirect
from flask_socketio import SocketIO,join_room
app = Flask(__name__)
boards = {}
socketio = SocketIO(app)
app.secret_key = "temporary"
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('wait.html')
@app.route('/dir')
def foo():
    if "name" in session:#fails here as session is <SecureCookieSession {}> instead of {'name' : 'craig}
        pass #just a filler
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("index"))#this line will cause to repetitively go back and forward from index to foo
@socketio.on('log')
def connection(request):
    if "name" not in session:
        join_room('waiting')#in my actual code the user waits for another person
        session['name'] = 'craig'
        socketio.emit('redirect', url_for('foo'),room= 'waiting')
    else:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':  
   socketio.run(app ,port=5000, debug=True)
```

and the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        Waiting...
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
        const socket = io();
        socket.emit("log", { data: "connection" });
        socket.on('redirect', (dest) => {
            window.location = dest;
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some resources for you. Documentation on [Flask context locals when using Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/implementation_notes.html#access-to-flask-s-context-globals). Also a [video I recorded explaining how to work with sessions in Flask-SocketIO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZ1yQTbtf5E). Hope these help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out flask-session did have the solution, I was just using it wrong forgetting these two lines of code when I initially tried:

```
Session(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, manage_session=False)# I did not have the manage_session
```

I also used

```
session.modified = True
```

though I'm not sure it is strictly necessary

Here is the updated server code:

```
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, url_for, redirect
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'temporary'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
Session(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, manage_session=False)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('wait.html')

@app.route('/dir')
def foo():
    if "name" in session:
        name = session['name']
        return f"Hello, {name}!"
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("index"))

@socketio.on('log')
def connection(request):
    print(session)
    if "name" not in session:
        join_room('waiting')
        session['name'] = 'craig'
        session.modified = True
        socketio.emit('redirect', url_for('foo'), room='waiting')
    else:
        session.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':  
   socketio.run(app, port=5200, debug=True)
```